# Adding the contents of 2 dictionaries when keys match, merging otherwise

Tags: .net, dictionary, coding-style

I've got a crawler which is summarising file types by directory.

Something like:

```
Class Directory
    Property Name As String
    Property TypeBreakdown As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Property Directories As ICollection(Of Directory)
End Class
```

I recurse into directories and add a `Directory` as appororiate. As I unwind up the stack, I want to aggregate the subdirectory breakdowns. Eg.

Assuming the `Source` directory has one `.cpp` file and 2 subdirectories (`SubDir`, `SubDir2`), I'd like something like this...

```
{
    "Name": "Source",
    "TypeBreakdown": {".cpp": 1, ".exe": 10, ".c": 110},
    "Directories": [
        {
            "Name": "SubDir",
            "TypeBreakdown": {".exe": 10, ".c": 10},
            "Directories": [],
        },
        {
            "Name": "SubDir2",
            "TypeBreakdown": {".c": 100},
            "Directories": [],
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm creating the various `TypeBreakdown` dictionaries but am unsure how I can combine such that:

If a key exists in either one but not both, include the key and value. If the key exists in both, include the key and sum the values.

Is there any way to do this without a very unwieldy for-loop which checks each key?

This needs to run on Vista without a framework update which means I'm targeting 3.0 so don't have access to LINQ

Comment: @SWeko thanks for editing but any .Net language would be fine - I just happened to give the example in VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to be able to use grouping. Something like:

```
var combinedTypeBreakDown = 
    firstTypeBreakDown.Concat(secondTypeBreakDown)
       .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value)
       .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum());
```

Comment: Apologies, I should've mentioned - This needs to run on Vista without a framework update so I'm targeting 3.0 = No LINQ

Comment: Gotcha. Do you know about [LinqBridge](https://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/)? Also available on [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/LinqBridge/).

Comment: @SWeko Not in [vanilla 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926(v=vs.90).aspx). It arrived in 3.5. and thanks shamp00, I wasn't aware of LinqBridge - reading now, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Without Linq:

```
    public Dictionary<string, int> CombineDictionaries(params Dictionary<string, int>[] dictionariesToCombine)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> result = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (Dictionary<string, int> dictionary in dictionariesToCombine)
        {
            foreach (var item in dictionary)
            {
                if (result.ContainsKey(item.Key))
                    result[item.Key] += item.Value;
                else
                    result.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

You call it with

```
var combinedBreakDown = CombineDictionaries(firstTypeBreakDown, secondTypeBreakDown);
```

Answer (score 1):

For your concrete case, I think it would be best if you add the combined breakdown as a property to the Directory class, something like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> GetFullTypeBreakdown()
{
  //assumes the client will not write to the result :D
  if ((Directories == null) || (Directories.Count == 0))
    return TypeBreakdown;

  var result = TypeBreakdown
    .Concat(Directories.SelectMany(d => d.GetFullTypeBreakdown()))
    .GroupBy(item => item.Key, item => item.Value)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g=> g.Sum());
  result.Dump();

  return result;
}
```

This recurses up the tree and calculates the combined breakdown. However, this uses a lot of LINQ, so you should at least use LinqBridge (I've used it before, and it's a lifesaver)